# Reading and Writing .TSV files in R

Tags: r

I have to do some analysis on a .tsv file for a project, and I am fairly new to R. I am having a problem when reading/writing a .tsv file in R. It seems like problem occurs when there is a quote ("") in the row.

Example of a few records in the original file are below:

```
org_id    org_name        description                    created at     
5762      Artifice        Artifice \comes from Latin     4/3/2014 19:42
1045      Access Dar      Microsoft "Nasdaq worldwide    7/4/2014 10:34
345       Living Asset    Lincoln Park Zoo               11/3/2014 19:42
2356      Adler Planet    Mission of black cat           12/2/2014 11:03
```

I am reading the file with the following code line:

```
orgs <- read.delim("C:/Users/orgs.tsv", header=TRUE)
```

After renaming the columns, I write the file using the code below:

```
write.table(orgs, file = "C:/Users/orgs_updated.tsv", row.names=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

Now when I try to read this file (orgs_updated.tsv) in another program, it does not like when there are quotes in any of the columns. I am reading the file again using the code below:

```
orgs_updated <- read.delim("C:/Users/orgs_updated.tsv", sep="", header=TRUE, quote="\"")
```

and the file is being read like this, i.e. being read wrong, and adding a wrong row.

```
org_id    name        description                    created at     
5762      Artifice        Artifice \comes from Latin     4/3/2014 19:42
1045      Access Dar      Microsoft                      Nasdaq worldwide    
7/4/2014 10:34
345       Living Asset    Lincoln Park Zoo               11/3/2014 19:42
2356      Adler Planet    Mission of black cat           12/2/2014 11:03
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I tried:

```
using the quote=FALSE option in write.table, 
not using quote option in the 2nd read.delim
changing sep = "" to sep ="\t"
```

but was not able to figure out the solution.

I will appreciate if someone can please help!!

Comment: I actually created dummy records, and forgot to rename the columns. In reality I am actually renaming them. I will make the correction in the question. Thanks for bringing that up @rawr

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the issue on my side. It would be very helpful if you hosted the test file somewhere and provided a link. (Dropbox?)

Comment: Actually I am not allowed to share the file. Let me create a dummy file quickly and then I will share the link.

Comment: @Myles Baker, I do not know how to share the file on Dropbox without an email ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try loading the file with the following (I created the file on my machine with comma-delimited instead of tab):

```
orgs <- read.delim("orgs.tsv", header=TRUE, allowEscapes=FALSE, sep=",",  quote="", na.strings="", comment.char="")
write.table(orgs, file = "orgs_updated.tsv", row.names=FALSE, sep="\t")
orgs_updated <- read.delim("orgs_updated.tsv", sep="", header=TRUE, quote="\"")

orgs_updated
  org_id     org_name                 description      created.at
1   5762     Artifice Artifice \\comes from Latin  4/3/2014 19:42
2   1045   Access Dar Microsoft "Nasdaq worldwide  7/4/2014 10:34
3    345 Living Asset            Lincoln Park Zoo 11/3/2014 19:42
4   2356 Adler Planet        Mission of black cat 12/2/2014 11:03
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried your code, but the result is the same. I can not read original orgs.tsv with sep=",", as the file is not comma delimited, so I just did not use the sep option. The original file orgs.tsv has 3967 records, but when I read orgs_updated.tsv, there are 3972 records, because of the problem with quotes. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Just change to `sep="\t"`. Does your file not have a common delimiter?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to use qmethod and file encoding options when writing the file. May be there is something wrong with how I am writing the file and that is why the 2nd time file is not read properly.

Comment: You shouldn't need file encoding. That just adds another piece of complexity to the puzzle. However, `qmethod` in `write.table` makes sense. You need to define a character not present in your data set that can escape special characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61810/discussion-between-myles-baker-and-nasia-jaffri).